# Capturing a Full-Length Webpage Screenshot (with a plugin/addon) in multiple browsers?

Tags: cross-browser, screenshot

I am trying to capture a screenshot of two versions of a website (one that's standards complaint and one that is not).

I would use broswershots.org, but only one of the websites has a public url.

Now I've already got full-length screenshots for IE and FF, but what can I do to get a full-length screenshot in Opera, Chrome and Safari?

Answer (score 0):

How did you do it on IE and FF?  There's some plugins and some apps, but none that I've wanted to work with.  I end up just take a series of screen shots (mac: *cmd shift 4*)  and pasting them together in photoshop.

Most of my apps/sites are under 2 "pages" so it's not that difficult of a process.

If I don't need a full resolution image of it I will zoom out on the page (*cmd shift -*), and can sometimes get the full page in one screenshot.